# What goes wrong when we formalize subsets as subtypes?

Tags: type-theory

In Nederpelt, Geuvers, Type theory and Formal Proof, they state that there are multiple ways to formalize subsets. The method they choose is to associate a predicate $T\to 2$ for each subset of the extension of type $T$. They state that another way to do it, is to let an object have multiple types, so that we can state that $x:T, x:S$, where $S\subset T$. They state that the problem with this is that **this makes type-checking undecidable**.

**But why is it necessarily a problem if type-checking is undecidable?** What is the problem with a type system that is able to check the type of *some* terms, but not all of them?

Comment: It definitely is an issue if you want to use your type theory to build a proof checker, where checking the validity of a proof is the same as checking a type